# iOS 8 - UILabel with gradient-colored text

Tags: ios, ios8, core-text

I'm trying to create a UILabel where the text is colored with a gradient. The gradient is dynamic, so I can't use a static image to do it. Further, every answer I've found uses some CGContext methods that have been deprecated (CGContextShowText in particular). The deprecation notes for these methods say "Use Core Text instead". However, I'm not all that familiar with Core Text, and I haven't been able to find any ways to do it through more searching. Does anybody know of a way to do this in iOS 8? Thanks!

Comment: The problem is that "gradient" is not a color. You would have to _draw_ the text and use it as a mask, or its outline as a clipping path, for a gradient. And that is not likely to be very legible text unless it is very big (and you wouldn't be able to change it - it would just be a drawing).

Answer (score 2):

I'm going to suggest a "workaround", namely, you can create a UIColor with an image, and an image can be created dynamically using any of the number of libraries out there.

The code for creating a gradient image would roughly be as follows (can probably be optimised to some extent):

```
CGSize size = CGSizeZero; // You should provide this yourself, height is important, width can be limited, for example 3

UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(size, NO, 0);

// Assumes fromColor and toColor are UIColors passed into this context
NSArray *colors = @[(id)[fromColor CGColor], (id)[toColor CGColor]];
CGFloat positions[2] = {0.f, 1.f};
CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
CGGradientRef gradient = CGGradientCreateWithColors(colorSpace, colors, positions);
CGColorSpaceRelease(colorSpace);

CGContextDrawLinearGradient(ctx, gradient, CGPointMake(0.f, 0.f), CGPointMake(0.f, size.height), kCGGradientDrawsBeforeStartLocation | kCGGradientDrawsAfterEndLocation);
CGGradientRelease(gradient);

UIImage *image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

// image contains the linear gradient image you need
UIColor *color = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:image];
// Simply assign this color to be the textColor of the label
```

Comment: It should, I used to do this, when gradients were still hip and cool, I don't see why it wouldn't work, obviously it will not scale, so animating etc is out of question, but other than that it can be a way to avoid building a completely custom label (rendering text can be a pain).

Comment: This seems to just be applying a gradient to the entire label, not just the text. I'm setting the textColor to be the UIColor created from the gradient pattern image, but for some reason it's just filling the entire label with the gradient

Comment: Right, I guess something has change then, it used to be applied only to the text. I'll see if I can whip some test up.